# GTK implementation of MessageBox

Tags: c, linux, gtk, x11

I have been trying to implement Win32's `MessageBox` using GTK. The app uses SDL/OpenGL, so this isn't a GTK app.

I handle the initialization (`gtk_init`) sort of stuff inside the `MessageBox` function as follows:

```
int MessageBox(HWND hwnd, const char* text, const char* caption, UINT type)
{
    GtkWidget *window = NULL;
    GtkWidget *dialog = NULL;

    gtk_init(&gtkArgc, &gtkArgv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(delete_event), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);
    // gcallback calls gtk_main_quit()
    gtk_init_add((GtkFunction)gcallback, NULL);

    if (type & MB_YESNO) {
        dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, GTK_MESSAGE_QUESTION, GTK_BUTTONS_YES_NO, text);
    } else {
        dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_OK, text);
    }

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(dialog), caption);
    gint result = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));

    gtk_main();

    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);

    if (type & MB_YESNO) {
        switch (result) {
        default:
        case GTK_RESPONSE_DELETE_EVENT:
        case GTK_RESPONSE_NO:
            return IDNO;
            break;
        case GTK_RESPONSE_YES:
            return IDYES;
            break;
        }
    }

    return IDOK;
}
```

Now, I am by no means an experienced GTK programmer, and I realize that I'm probably doing something horribly wrong.

However, my problem is that the last dialog popped up with this function staying around until the process exits. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hmm, ok. I'd suggest code like this, then:

```c
typedef struct {
    int type;
    int result;
} DialogData;
    
static gboolean
display_dialog(gpointer user_data)
{
    DialogData *dialog_data = user_data;
    GtkWidget *dialog;
    
    if (dialog_data->type & MB_YESNO)
        dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(...);
    else
        dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(...);
    
    // Set title, etc.
    
    dialog_data->result = gtk_dialog_run(...);
    
    gtk_main_quit();  // Quits the main loop run in MessageBox()
    
    return FALSE;
}
    
int MessageBox(...)
{
    DialogData dialog_data;
    
    dialog_data.type = type;
    
    gtk_idle_add(display_dialog, &dialog_data);
    
    gtk_main();
    
    // Do stuff based on dialog_data.result
}
```

The struct is required because you need to pass around a couple pieces of data. The `gtk_idle_add()` call adds a method to be run when the main loop is running and idle, and the `FALSE` return value from the `display_dialog()` call means that it's only run once.  After we get the result from the dialog, we quit the main loop. That'll cause the `gtk_main()` in your main `MessageBox()` method to return, and you'll be able to access the result from there.

Answer (score 9):

To manage a dialog box with GTK+, use a GtkDialog and [gtk_dialog_run()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkDialog.html#gtk-dialog-run) instead of managing a window and a main loop by yourself.

**EDIT / ADDENDUM :**

What I mean is "just use" : I don't understand why you create a windows you never use and a main loop which seems useless (at least from the piece of code you posted). You can write something as short as :

```
int MessageBox(HWND hwnd, const char* text, const char* caption, UINT type)
{
    GtkWidget *dialog ;

    /* Instead of 0, use GTK_DIALOG_MODAL to get a modal dialog box */

    if (type & MB_YESNO)
        dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL, 0, GTK_MESSAGE_QUESTION, GTK_BUTTONS_YES_NO, text );
    else
        dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL, 0, GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_OK, text );


    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(dialog), caption);
    gint result = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy( GTK_WIDGET(dialog) );

    if (type & MB_YESNO)
    {
        switch (result)
        {
        default:
        case GTK_RESPONSE_DELETE_EVENT:
        case GTK_RESPONSE_NO:
            return IDNO;
        case GTK_RESPONSE_YES:
            return IDYES;
        }
        return IDOK;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A few things:

You are creating (and not using) an unnecessary toplevel window, named `window`.  You can just delete these lines:

```
window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(delete_event), NULL);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);
```

Also, the flow doesn't seem quite right.  `gtk_main()` starts the GTK main loop, which blocks until something exits it.  `gtk_dialog_run()` also starts a main loop, but it exits as soon as one of the buttons is clicked.

I think it might be enough for you to remove the `gtk_init_add()` and `gtk_main()` calls, and simply deal with the return value.  Also the `gtk_widget_destroy()` call is unnecessary, as the dialog window is automatically destroyed when gtk_dialog_run() returns.