# Qt implementation of MessageBox

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Referencing an earlier question: [GTK implementation of MessageBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263/gtk-implementation-of-messagebox)

I have a question very much like that one, except substituting Qt for GTK.

As in that question, what is the least I would need to do to show a message dialog using Qt, from an application that is not already a Qt application?

I presume something like the following would need to occur:

- Initialize Qt and its event loop
- Install idle callback to invoke dialog
- Quit event loop and finalize Qt when dialog is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

You are tring to show a message box from a console application right ?

If this is correct you need to add this line in your pro file:

> QT       += gui

After you have done that in your main.cpp file write something like this. Qt creates an event loop for you

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QApplication>




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMessageBox::information(NULL,"Hello","Salut","Ok");

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: "from an application that is not already a Qt application", but you're assuming that a QMake `.pro` file already exists.

Comment: Yes, I would not be using QMake. Build config is not a concern for me.

I don't see anything here that would tell the main event loop to terminate. Does the message box become the "main window," thus causing the event loop to terminate when it closes?